# Try to run OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing demo

Tags: java, android, opencv, opengl-es

hi all i am try to run OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing demo. i am not getting where is the problem. some one can help me please.

```
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mixed_sample from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity$1.onManagerConnected(Tutorial2Activity.java:49)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1106)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1123)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-29 17:14:44.556: E/AndroidRuntime(7242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The problem is that Android can't find the native library, probably because something during compiling and packaging the apk went wrong or isn't set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

remove android library reference = true from project properties

Comment: please add some description to your answer, what you did and why did that worked.